# Creating pyspark dataframe inside of custom package?

Tags: python, pyspark, package, databricks

I'm a bit confused on best practices and how to create spark sessions inside of a package, where the package could be used on databricks or local.

But lets say I have a function that takes in some lists or dicts of data, and expected output is a pyspark dataframe with the data.
I think the single session should suffice, so will need to check if a session exists and if not create one.

But I'm just not sure how to do this in a function?

This is my code for how it's dont inside of a jupyter notebook, I don't know if this is the best way anyways...sometimes I get an error using this method.

```py
try:
  conf = pyspark.SparkConf().set('spark.driver.host','127.0.0.1')
  sc = pyspark.SparkContext(master='local', appName='example',conf=conf)
  sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
  print("Binding")
except ValueError:
    print("Spark session already created")
```

And if I need to create a dataframe, here I use:

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=cSchema)
```

I also found this documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html
But doesn't seem to work for me, I get "spark" is not defined:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
        .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
        .getOrCreate()

....
spark.createDataFrame(test_list, schema=cSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the definitely the correct way:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
     .builder \
     .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
     .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

although stylistic I would do it like that for readability

```
spark = (SparkSession 
         .builder 
         .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example")           
         .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") 
         .getOrCreate())
```

It will create a Session or just give you the existing one. It shouldn't be undefined is there an error you have? What version of spark do you have?

I use spark locally and also on Databricks and I use that method constantly

To answer on how you should do it method wise I would just write a function in a utility library for example:

```
def getSparkSession():
    return (SparkSession 
            .builder 
            .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example")           
            .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") 
            .getOrCreate())
```

and than use it in your code:

```
spark = getSparkSession()
```